# Remove element from LinkedList by value (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove a Node from LinkedList by it's value however it doesn't seem to work.
LinkedList class (with node):

```
public class Node<T>
    {
        private T info;
        private Node<T> next;

        public Node(T x, Node<T> next)
        {
            this.info = x;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public Node<T> GetNext()
        {
            return this.next;
        }

        public void SetNext(Node<T> next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public T GetInfo()
        {
            return this.info;
        }

        public void SetInfo(T x)
        {
            this.info = x;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.info.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class List<T>
    {

        private Node<T> first;

        public List()
        {
            this.first = null;
        }

        public Node<T> GetFirst()
        {
            return this.first;
        }

        public Node<T> Add(Node<T> pos, T x)
        {
            Node<T> temp = new Node<T>(x, null);

            if (pos == null)
            {
                temp.SetNext(this.first);
                this.first = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                temp.SetNext(pos.GetNext());
                pos.SetNext(temp);
            }

            return temp;
        }

        public Node<T> Remove(Node<T> pos)
        {
            if (this.first == pos)
                this.first = pos.GetNext();
            else
            {
                Node<T> prevPos = this.GetFirst();
                while (prevPos.GetNext() != pos)
                    prevPos = prevPos.GetNext();
                prevPos.SetNext(pos.GetNext());
            }

            Node<T> nextPos = pos.GetNext();
            pos.SetNext(null);

            return nextPos;
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            string str = "[";
            Node<T> pos = this.first;
            while (pos != null)
            {
                str += pos.GetInfo().ToString();
                if (pos.GetNext() != null)
                    str += ", ";
                pos = pos.GetNext();
            }

            str += "]";

            return str;
        }
    }
```

That's the function:

```
public void Del(string info)
        {
            Node<T> previousNode = null, obsoleteNode = null, nextNode = null;
            Node<T> pos = this.first;
            while (pos != null)
            {
                if (pos == this.first && this.first.GetInfo().ToString() == info)
                {
                    Node<T> temp = pos;
                    this.first = this.first.GetNext();
                    temp = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    previousNode = pos;
                    if (previousNode != null)
                        obsoleteNode = previousNode.GetNext();
                    if (nextNode == null)
                        nextNode = pos.GetNext().GetNext();
                    if (obsoleteNode != null)
                    {
                        if (obsoleteNode.GetInfo().ToString() == info)
                            previousNode.SetNext(nextNode);
                    }
                }
                pos = pos.GetNext();
            }

        }
```

In VS autos it shows that obsoleteNode is actually null but i can't understand why.
All other values are okay, except pos, it gets somehow the last node in the list instead of first but the this.first himself is okay.
What can be the problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you are reinventing the wheel?

Comment: At first glance nextNode is going to persist across the end of the deletion loop which I don't think is what you want, and it'll also fail if `previousNode.GetNext() == null`. I think you want to move the nextNode set into the obsolete != null check (or even the info check too) and fetch it from obsoleteNode.GetNext() always. Not sure why obsoleteNode would be wrong.

Comment: Where does your exception occur? At which point in the code are you talking about those specific values?

Comment: In the function Del, where i have  if (obsoleteNode != null)

Comment: Is the Remove() function work well? If yes, i suggest you to use the same algorithm, but compare value instead of object.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is actually to take three adjacent nodes and check the value of the middle one against the given value. If they match, i want to take the first one and to connect it directly to third one, so it is like I'm breaking the connection (isolating) the middle one.

Comment: The Remove() function seems to be working however, it doesn't work the way i want it because the next thing i want to do is to take specific nodes which are stored in the stack (which were copied previously from the list) and to remove them from the list and in this case the Remove doesn't work maybe because it's breaking somehow the reference. Anyways, i want to stick to this method, I'm pretty sure the algorithm is okay but the implementation is not.

Comment: P.S.: Any reason you aren't using properties?

Comment: No special reason. Does it matter?

Comment: @Guest: conciseness, and C# conventions

Comment: @Guest : Your algorithm isn't good cause your variable "NextNode" is assign only the first time. And if your list have only 1 item, not equals at your value, you will have an "null reference exception" on this line : 'pos.GetNext().GetNext(); '

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed i forgot to check if pos.GetNext() isn't null. It works now

Comment: guys, use answers instead of comments, that way they can be voted on and marked as the answer!